# System bootloader not found

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dual-boot, grub, uefi

[image: fdisk -l]I recently installed UbuntuDDE 20.04 LTS to be able to dual boot with Windows 10. After following the instructions online, I was able to get it up and running. However, after shutting down my PC and trying to boot into Windows 10, I get the message "System bootloader not found. Initializing Defaults." and then it would send me back to the startup menu.

I tried to boot back into UbuntuDDE, but it also failed and sent me back to the startup menu. I also don't seem to have a GRUB menu either. It would be my UEFI prompting for my boot device options.

EDIT: This is what I got after typing the commands after booting Ubuntu setup through my USB:
[image: After typing in bootctl]

Is there any sort of way I can get this fixed?

[image: After typing in efibootmgr and find /boot/efi]

EDIT3: sudofdisk -l
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In your BIOS have you tried booting from other disks?  The boot-loader is pointed to a disk without a boot-loader so you may have selected the wrong boot device.

Comment: You could try booting from a liveCD, then installing grub with something like `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.  There are some [good suggestions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

Comment: @Stewart It's 2020, so hopefully not many people still rely on the legacy BIOS CSM. OP also mentions UEFI, so there are no "boot devices" or bootloaders embedded in initial sectors. The bootloader is just a file on the EFI System Partition and the corresponding boot entries need to be managed through `efibootmgr`.

Comment: Please boot from a live USB and then edit your question, adding the output of `bootctl` (if available), `efibootmgr -v` and `find /boot/efi`.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. Does Windows have fast startup on, or need chkdsk. Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu and turn fast start up off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @TooTea I went into my USB boot device and booted the setup and typed in the commands. The results are the pictures.

Comment: Thanks. Something got seriously messed up. Your EFI variables look for the Windows bootloader in an EFI system partition on one physical disk and GRUB in an EFI system partition, but on a different physical disk. That shouldn't ever happen. You're supposed to have just one EFI system partition in the system. Please add the output of `fdisk -l` and describe what kinds of disks are there in the system and what's supposed to be installed where.

Comment: @TooTea I added the output for fdisk -l

Comment: You gotta run it as root to get a usable output, that means `sudo fdisk -l`. Sorry, I didn't notice you're running these commands as an ordinary user.

Comment: ...or `lsblk` will probably work

Comment: @TooTea added the sudo fdisk -l output